# calculate speed using corelocation framework is showing in simulator not in device-ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I am calculating the speed as below using core location framework. However it is working in simulator not in device(In device it show -1).

```
  self.curSpeedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km/h", newLocation.speed];


 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
 {
 loc = locations.lastObject;
  if (_startDate == nil) // first update!
 {
    _startDate = loc.timestamp;
    totalDistance = 0;
 }
 else
 {
    totalDistance += [loc distanceFromLocation:_lastLocation];
    CLLocationDistance distanceChange = [loc 
    distanceFromLocation:_lastLocation];
    NSTimeInterval sinceLastUpdate = [loc.timestamp
   timeIntervalSinceDate:_lastLocation.timestamp];
   // speedLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f km/h", 
 // (distanceChange)/(sinceLastUpdate)];
  self.curSpeedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km/h",
   loc.speed];
    _lastLocation = loc;
   distanceLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km/h", 
  (totalDistance/metersInKM)];
  NSTimeInterval travelTime = [loc.timestamp 
   timeIntervalSinceDate:_startDate];        
    if (travelTime > 0)
    {
        avgSpeed = (totalDistance) / (travelTime);
       _avgSpeed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f km/h", avgSpeed];
        NSLog(@"Average speed %.2f", avgSpeed);
        _totTimetaken=(travelTime/60/60);

    }
 }
}
```

Please advice.

Comment: Are location services enabled for your app in said device?

Comment: How to you test your speed with the device? `-1` is when it can't find/guess the speed. This can occur if the position accuracy is too low.

Comment: However i can the distance

Comment: May be unrelated, but it seems like you are using the deprecated method locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation (judging from your "newLocation" variable).  
Can you show a bit more code?

Comment: i edited my code please check it

Comment: As long as you are getting location updates it doesn't make sense to always get an invalid speed value every time and only when using the device.
Ruling out the location services being disabled and maybe a problem with your device's GPS, i'm inclined to suggest following @Crazyrems approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This value reflects the instantaneous speed of the device in the direction of its current heading. A negative value indicates an invalid speed. Because the actual speed can change many times between the delivery of subsequent location events, you should use this property for informational purposes only.

So when you're gonna have points more often, this should actually give you the speed.
Since you have the distance, consider using the distance to find the speed.

Comment: Even i tried using distance it is not giving the correct speed.

Comment: speedLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f km/h", 
  (distanceChange)/(sinceLastUpdate)];